# Python Openfermion Package - Module not found errors

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to run a script that, among other things, relies on the Openfermion package from Google.
I'm also using QuTiP, PySCF, and Openfermion-PySCF.

When trying to run my script I've gotten a slew of errors, depending on my method of installation.

I've created a Python environment with `Python==3.7`.
When I use Openfermion on version 0.9.0 (having installed with `conda install -c psi4 openfermion`) I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from setupFunc import *
  File "/home/anders/Documents/setupFunc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from moleculeClass import *
  File "/home/anders/Documents/moleculeClass.py", line 9, in <module>
    from openfermionpyscf import run_pyscf
  File "/home/anders/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openfermionpyscf/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ._pyscf_molecular_data import PyscfMolecularData
  File "/home/anders/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openfermionpyscf/_pyscf_molecular_data.py", line 20, in <module>
    from openfermion.chem import MolecularData
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openfermion.chem'
```

The (current) output from `-pip show openfermion` is;

```
Name: openfermion
Version: 0.9.0
Summary: The electronic structure package for quantum computers.
Home-page: http://www.openfermion.org
Author: The OpenFermion Developers
Author-email: help@openfermion.org
License: Apache 2
Location: /home/anders/anaconda3/envs/vqeenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: numpy, scipy, h5py, future, jupyter, nbformat, networkx, matplotlib, pubchempy, six
Required-by: openfermionpyscf
```

If I install using pip, i.e. `python -m pip install --user openfermion`, I get the same error.
I've also tried using Openfermion==0.10.0 and 0.11.0, and once a version 1.0.0 - but in every case they give the same type of error; of a module not found - although in some cases it points to `openfermion.hamiltonians`, rather than `openfermion.chem`.

On some versions I also get an error of "failing to import comb, from scipy.misc" - but I know how to fix that.

To replicate my issue, try creating an env with the following;

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file spec-vqe-hp.txt
# platform: linux-64
@EXPLICIT
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/_libgcc_mutex-0.1-conda_forge.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/ca-certificates-2019.11.28-hecc5488_0.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/intel-openmp-2020.0-166.conda
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/ld_impl_linux-64-2.33.1-h53a641e_8.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libgfortran-3.0.0-1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libgfortran-ng-7.3.0-hdf63c60_5.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libstdcxx-ng-9.2.0-hdf63c60_2.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libgomp-9.2.0-h24d8f2e_2.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/mkl-2020.0-166.conda
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/_openmp_mutex-4.5-0_gnu.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libgcc-ng-9.2.0-h24d8f2e_2.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/expat-2.2.9-he1b5a44_2.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/fftw-3.3.8-nompi_h7f3a6c3_1110.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/gmp-6.2.0-he1b5a44_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/icu-64.2-he1b5a44_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/jpeg-9c-h14c3975_1001.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/pyscf/linux-64/libcint-3.0.19-0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libffi-3.2.1-he1b5a44_1006.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libiconv-1.15-h516909a_1005.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libllvm9-9.0.1-hc9558a2_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libopenblas-0.3.7-h5ec1e0e_6.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libuuid-2.32.1-h14c3975_1000.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libxc-4.3.4-h6e990d7_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libxkbcommon-0.10.0-he1b5a44_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/metis-5.1.0-he1b5a44_1005.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/ncurses-6.1-hf484d3e_1002.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/nspr-4.25-he1b5a44_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/openssl-1.1.1d-h516909a_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/pcre-8.43-he1b5a44_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/pthread-stubs-0.4-h14c3975_1001.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/tbb-2019.9-hc9558a2_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/xorg-libxau-1.0.9-h14c3975_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/xorg-libxdmcp-1.1.3-h516909a_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/xz-5.2.4-h14c3975_1001.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/zlib-1.2.11-h516909a_1006.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/gettext-0.19.8.1-hc5be6a0_1002.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/glpk-4.65-he80fd80_1002.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/hdf5-1.10.2-hc401514_3.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libblas-3.8.0-14_openblas.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libclang-9.0.1-default_hde54327_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libpng-1.6.37-hed695b0_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libxcb-1.13-h14c3975_1002.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libxml2-2.9.10-hee79883_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/readline-8.0-hf8c457e_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/tk-8.6.10-hed695b0_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/freetype-2.10.0-he983fc9_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/libcblas-3.8.0-14_openblas.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/liblapack-3.8.0-14_openblas.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/sqlite-3.30.1-hcee41ef_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/dsdp-5.8-h23d7751_1203.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/fontconfig-2.13.1-h86ecdb6_1001.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/gsl-2.6-h294904e_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/nss-3.47-he751ad9_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/python-3.7.6-h357f687_2.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/suitesparse-5.6.0-h717dc36_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/certifi-2019.11.28-py37_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/cvxopt-1.2.4-py37h93fb107_202.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/cython-0.29.14-py37he1b5a44_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/decorator-4.4.1-py_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/future-0.18.2-py37_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/glib-2.58.3-py37h6f030ca_1002.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/kiwisolver-1.1.0-py37hc9558a2_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/numpy-1.18.1-py37h95a1406_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/pyparsing-2.4.6-py_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/six-1.14.0-py37_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/tornado-6.0.3-py37h516909a_2.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/cycler-0.10.0-py_2.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/dbus-1.13.6-he372182_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/gstreamer-1.14.5-h36ae1b5_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/h5py-2.8.0-py37h3010b51_1003.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/python-dateutil-2.8.1-py_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/scipy-1.4.1-py37h921218d_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/setuptools-45.2.0-py37_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/gst-plugins-base-1.14.5-h0935bb2_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/joblib-0.14.1-py_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/matplotlib-base-3.1.3-py37h250f245_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/networkx-2.4-py_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/numexpr-2.7.1-py37hb3f55d8_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/pyscf/linux-64/pyscf-1.7.0-py37h39e3cac_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/qutip-4.5.0-py37h9de70de_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/wheel-0.34.2-py_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/psi4/linux-64/openfermion-0.9-py37hd763080_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/pip-20.0.2-py_2.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/qt-5.12.5-hd8c4c69_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/scikit-learn-0.22.1-py37hcdab131_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/pyqt-5.12.3-py37hcca6a23_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/matplotlib-3.1.3-py37_0.tar.bz2
```

p.s. I am running Linux (Ubuntu) 64-bit on a virtual machine from Windows 7, and am using conda 4.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps are for setting up your Conda environment properly:

Step 1: Create and activate a new Conda environment (You can replace `test` by your preferred name)

```
conda create -n test python=3.7 -y
conda activate test
```

Step 2: Install the latest `openfermion`, `openfermionpyscf` and `pyscf`

```
pip install -U openfermion openfermionpyscf pyscf
```

Step 3: Testing

```
$ python                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Python 3.7.10 (default, Feb 26 2021, 10:16:00) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openfermion
>>> import openfermionpyscf
>>> from openfermionpyscf import run_pyscf
>>> import pyscf
```

If there is no error in this step then you should be able to run your code.

NOTE: Answer is updated based on the follow-up discussion.

Comment: I get this output, after having made the environment and pasted code.
`/home/anders/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyscf/lib/misc.py:47: H5pyDeprecationWarning: Using default_file_mode other than 'r' is deprecated. Pass the mode to h5py.File() instead.
  h5py.get_config().default_file_mode = 'a'
>>> from openfermionpyscf import pyscf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'pyscf' from 'openfermionpyscf' (/home/anders/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openfermionpyscf/__init__.py)
>>>`

Comment: The way you imported `pyscf` is incorrect. To import this, you have to use `import pyscf`. In your error logs, the program failed to run due to the import of `run_pyscf` so I tested to import it from `openfermionpyscf`. Let me update the answer for importing `pyscf` as well.

Comment: I now did "import pyscf" as well, and when I do `from openfermionpyscf import run_pyscf` I no longer get any errors - but it seems to be continuously running; or perhaps that's just the Python itself?
Any how, I also need QuTiP in order to run the script(s) in question. However, after installing it with `conda install qutip` (into the test environment) I once again run into `ImportError: cannot import name 'MolecularData' from 'openfermion.hamiltonians'`

Comment: Since you created the Conda environment, you should better use pip to install packages so please try ‘pip install qutip’ instead. Also, importing run_pyscf may take time so just let it run. At least now there is no error when importing it.

Comment: Trying to install qutip via. `pip install -U qutip` yields a tonne of errors, (299 lines). The last two lines are;
`ERROR: Could not build wheels for qutip which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`

I've already googled it, and the suggestions I could find were to update/install pip, but I've already made sure it was up to date. P.S. Shouldn't there be an `pyscf` installed as well, in the third line of code you wrote originally?

Comment: Yeah you need to install `pyscf` first before importing it. For `qutip`, I tried to install from pip `pip install -U qutip` and it worked without any issue. Make sure you have already activated the Conda enviroment `conda activate test` before using `pip`. You can also have a look at the tutorial here: http://qutip.org/docs/4.1/installation.html

Comment: That's very odd. I do `pip show` on Openfermion, PySCF, and OpenfermionPySCF and get Openfermion 1.0.0, PySCF on 1.7.5.1 and openfermionpyscf is at 0.5. With `pip -V` I get `pip 21.0.1 from /home/anders/anaconda3/envs/test2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)` - However! When I do `pip install -U qutip` I get the error above. And this is all inside the same environment, as described above.

Comment: Firstly, run `conda remove qutip`. Secondly, repeat the above steps once more time to test on a new Conda environment (e.g., test3) and install all 4 packages you need. If it does not work for you, you should ask a new question since this question was originally for `openfermion`.

Comment: Getting the same errors; even with a fresh environment. I will ask another question, thanks for all your help any way!

Comment: I have updated the results removing `qutip`. Let ask another question for another discussion to avoid a long discussion here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483391/python-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-installing-qutip

Discussion for QuTiP problem.