# Python ERROR - could not build wheels for installing QuTiP

Tags: python, python-wheel

(You can look through discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478357/python-openfermion-package-module-not-found-errors/66479891?noredirect=1#comment117531540_66479891) for additional context)

I'm trying to run a script that uses `Openfermion, PySCF, Openfermionpyscf`, and `QuTiP` packages for Python. I'm running Linux (Ubuntu) 64bit on a virtual machine (off of Win7, 64bit).

Following discussion in the links above I have managed to succesfully install Openfermion and PySCF, but get the following error upon using `pip -U install qutip`

```
Building wheels for collected packages: qutip
  Building wheel for qutip (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
...
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for qutip
Failed to build qutip
ERROR: Could not build wheels for qutip which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

The "..." in the above is for the sake of brevity, as the actual error message encompasses some 299 lines.

I tried this installation in an environment with python=3.7, and with nothing else installed, but I run into errors either way.

To recreate my issue; try

```
$ conda create -n test python=3.7 -y
$ conda activate test
$ pip install -U openfermion openfermionpyscf pyscf qutip
```

Other things I have tried

- Installing via. conda, which led to various errors (being unable to use modules `Openfermion.chem` or `Openfermion.Hamiltonians` as described in the original problem.
- Removing the entirety of my qutip, openfermion, pyscf installations, making a new environment and reinstalling everything - tried with both conda and pip in a new environment each time.

**EDIT:** While I have no resolved the `pip install QuTiP` errors (regarding wheels), even after verying that my `conda -V` is 4.9.2 as desired, and after attempting an upgrade `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` (already up to date) I have found a work-around by install via. Conda.
As long as I install QuTiP with conda, I get no issues. And, as it turns out, the errors I previously had with conda installations were due to an outdated segment of code in the scripts I was trying to run.

While the issue is not resolved (I still cannot install via. pip), it's not imperative any longer.

Comment: It's actually weird to me since I ran the above 3 command lines and got all packages installed successfully. Which `anaconda` version are you using? (Mine is `4.9.2`)

Comment: https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads

Comment: With `conda -V` I see get `conda 4.9.2` - so there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I even tried updating anaconda by downloading latest version (from your link, but it's the same as I had) and doing bash ... -u.
It comes out with the same error on trying to install QuTiP

Comment: Can you try this to upgrade `pip` version: `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` and reinstall `qutip` by new `pip` again?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I already tried `pip --upgrade` but without the additional options. By running `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` and trying to reinstall QuTiP I get the same error as before (with the unable to build wheel).